# vector.resize() is crashing the program

Tags: c++, valgrind, stdvector

```
  cout<<tp.max_size()<<endl;
  cout<<2 * nA * B<<endl;
  cout<<nA<<endl;
  cout<<B<<endl;
  tp.resize(B, vector<vector<int>>(nA, vector<int>(2, -1)));
```

tp is declared as `vector<vector<vector<int>>>`. When the code reaches `tp.resize` it crashes even though the size is smaller than max_size.

max_size = 384307168202282325

nA * B * 2 = 2105038400

nA = 32

B = 100000089

What could be the reason for the crash?

Comment: The max_size is not the maximum available size, it's the maximum size the container can manage.  The available size depends on how much free memory you have (and possibly how much virtual memory).

Comment: ***What could be the reason for the crash?*** If you are on linux the OOM_Killer could have killed your process when it began to hog too much of the virtual memory you have available.

Comment: Clearly your program needs  sizeof(int) * 2105038400 = 8GB(Approximately) memory, you might need to think about this again.

Comment: Yeah... I used a map instead of a multi-dimensional vector & that solved the problem.

Here's how I mapped the elements:
t[i][j][k] = map[ str(i) + " " + str(j) + " " + str(k) ]